# Regex: how to match any string until whitespace, or until punctuation followed by whitespace?

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm trying to write a regular expression which will find URLs in a plain-text string, so that I can wrap them with anchor tags. I know there are [expressions already available for this](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls), but I want to create my own, mostly because I want to know how it works.

Since it's not going to break anything if my regex fails, my plan is to write something fairly simple. So far that means: 1) match "www" or "http" at the start of a word 2) keep matching until the word ends.

I can do that, AFAICT. I have this: `\b(http|www).?[^\s]+`

Which works on `foo www.example.com bar http://www.example.com` etc.

The problem is that if I give it `foo www.example.com, http://www.example.com` it thinks that the comma is a part of the URL.

So, if I am to use one expression to do this, I need to change "...and stop when you see whitespace" to "...and stop when you see whitespace or a piece of punctuation right before whitespace". **This is what I'm not sure how to do.**

At the moment, a solution I'm thinking of running with is just adding another test – matching the URL, and then on the next line moving any sneaky punctuation. This just isn't as elegant.

Note: I am writing this in PHP.

*Aside: why does replacing `\s` with `\b` in the expression above not seem to work?*

---

ETA:

Thanks everyone!

This is what I eventually ended up with, based on Explosion Pills's advice:

```
function add_links( $string ) {
    function replace( $arr ) {
        if ( strncmp( "http", $arr[1], 4) == 0 ) {
            return "<a href=$arr[1]>$arr[1]</a>$arr[2]$arr[3]";
        } else {
            return "<a href=" . "http://" . $arr[1] . ">$arr[1]</a>$arr[2]$arr[3]";
        }
    }
return preg_replace_callback( '/\b((?:http|www).+?)((?!\/)[\p{P}]+)?(\s|$)/x', replace, $string );
}
```

I added a callback so that all of the links would start with http://, and did some fiddling with the way it handles punctuation.

It's probably not the Best way to do things, but it works. I've learned a lot about this in the last little while, but there is still more to learn!

Comment: Hi @Nick, welcome to SO.  +1 for a well-formatted question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/
    \b       # Initial word boundary
    (        # Start capture
    (?:      # Non-capture group
    http|www # http or www (alternation)
    )        # end group
    .+?      # reluctant match for at least one character until...
    )        # End capture
    (        # Start capture
    [,.]+    # ...one or more of either a comma or period.
             # add more punctuation as needed
    )?       # End optional capture
    (\s|$) # Followed by either a space character or end of string
    /x', '<a href="\1">\1</a>\2\3'
```

...is probably what you are going for.  I think it's still imperfect, but it should at least work for your needs.

*Aside: I think this is because `\b` matches punctuation too*

Comment: This is a great way to explain regex!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\b(http:|www\.)(?:[^\s,.!?]|[,.!?](?!\s))+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3546m).

Means, match anything, but whitespace `,.!?` OR match `,.!?` when it is not followed by whitespace.

*Aside: A [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is not a character or a set of characters, you can't put it into a character class. It is a zero width assertion, that is matching on a change from a word character to a non-word character. Here, I believe, `\b` in a character class is interpreted as the backspace character (the string escape sequence).*

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie in the dot, which means "any character" in regex-speak.  You'll probably have to escape it:

```
\b(http|www)\.?[^\s]+
```

Then, the question mark means 0 or 1 so you've said "an optional dot" which is not what you want (right?):

```
\b(http|www)\.[^\s]+
```

Now, it will only match `http.` and `www.` so you need to tell what other characters you'll let it accept:

```
\b(http|www)\.[^\s\w]+
```

or

```
\b(http|www)\.[^\sa-zA-Z]+
```

So now you're saying,

- at the boundary of a word
- check for `http` or `www`
- put a dot
- allow any range `a-z` or `A-Z`, don't allow any whitespace character
- one or more of those

Note - I haven't tested these but they are hopefully correct-ish.

---

*Aside (my take on it)* - the `\s` means 'whitespace'.  The `\b` means 'word boundary'.  The `[]` means 'an allowed character range'.  The `^` means 'not'.  The `+` means 'one or more'.

So when you say `[^\b]+` you're saying 'don't allow word boundaries in this range of characters, and there must be one or more' and since there's nothing else there > nothing else is allowed > there's not one or more > it probably breaks.

Comment: A word boundary is not a character or a set of characters, you can't put it into a character class. It is a zero width assertion, that is matching on a change from a word character to a non-word character. Here, I believe, `\b` in a character class is interpreted as the backspace character (the string escape sequence).

Comment: The dot is optional, because after `http` there is no dot, so it will not match from http on.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
\b(http|www).?[\w\.\/]+
```