# Regular expressions in python to match Twitter handles

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I'm trying to use regular expressions to capture all Twitter handles within a tweet body. The challenge is that I'm trying to get handles that

1. Contain a specific string
2. Are of unknown length
3. May be followed by either

   - punctuation
   - whitespace
   - or the end of string.

For example, for each of these strings, Ive marked *in italics* what I'd like to return.

> "@handle what is your problem?" *[RETURN '@handle']*
>
> "what is your problem @handle?" *[RETURN '@handle']*
>
> "@123handle what is your problem @handle123?" *[RETURN '@123handle', '@handle123']*

This is what I have so far:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(@.*handle.*?)\W','hi @123handle, hello @handle123')
['@123handle']
# This misses the handles that are followed by end-of-string
```

I tried modifying to include an `or` character allowing the end-of-string character. Instead, it just returns the whole string.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(@.*handle.*?)(?=\W|$)','hi @123handle, hello @handle123')
['@123handle, hello @handle123']
# This looks like it is too greedy and ends up returning too much
```

How can I write an expression that will satisfy both conditions?

I've looked at a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932012/regex-how-to-match-any-string-until-whitespace-or-until-punctuation-followed-b) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713310/how-to-specify-space-or-end-of-string-and-space-or-start-of-string) places, but am still stuck.

Comment: You should not have added `.*` between `@` and `handle`. Use `\w*`. Like `r'@\w*handle\w*'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to match strings starting with `@`, then having 0+ word chars, then `handle`, and then again 0+ word chars.

Use

```
r'@\w*handle\w*'
```

or - to avoid matching `@`+word chars in emails:

```
r'\B@\w*handle\w*'
```

See the [Regex 1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jW4xL1/1) and the [Regex 2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jW4xL1/2) (the `\B` non-word boundary requires a non-word char or start of string to be right before the `@`).

Note that the `.*` is a greedy dot matching pattern that matches any characters other than newline, as many as possible. `\w*` only matches 0+ characters (also as many as possible) but from the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` set if the `re.UNICODE` flag is not used (and it is not used in your code).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/T1bZx4):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'@\w*handle\w*')
test_str = "@handle what is your problem?\nwhat is your problem @handle?\n@123handle what is your problem @handle123?\n"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => ['@handle', '@handle', '@123handle', '@handle123']
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches only handles that contain this range of characters -> `/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/`.

```
s = "@123handle what is your problem @handle123?"
print re.findall(r'\B(@[\w\d_]+)', s)
>>> ['@123handle', '@handle123']
s = '@The quick brown fox@jumped over the LAAZY @_dog.'
>>> ['@The', '@_dog']
```

Comment: This will also extract a `@` from `"Some@email.com"`.

Comment: Updating my post now.